# Почему не работает вызов jquery плагина в консоли?

Tags: jquery, typescript

Так плагин отображает 'test' в консоли, но только один раз при обновлении страницы.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.RangeSlider = function (): JQuery {
    console.log('test');
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$('#range-slider').RangeSlider();
```

Но если если вызвать его из консоли

```
$('#range-slider').RangeSlider();
```

то выдает ошибку.
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).RangeSlider is not a function
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

jQuery подключен через cdn

```
$ === jQuery (true)
```

если ввести весь код плагина в консоли

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.RangeSlider = function () {
    console.log('test');
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

// то вызов работает
$('#range-slider').RangeSlider();  // test
```

Answer (score -3):

Нужно добавить в плагин

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Зачем минусовать правильный ответ?